# How to write clean code for drag and drop in Android Studio for use in more than one activities

Tags: android, kotlin, drag-and-drop

here's a quick question about writing clean code for drag and drop functionality.  I already know how to code for a drag and drop, but I'm confused on what to do if that functionality is required for more than one activity in Android Studio. Is it better to implement View.OnDragListener() on each activity or is it better to write one activity and have multiple activities access the activity with the View.OnDragListener() implementation. An example of the second method would be:

```
class DragDrop(): View.OnDragListener{
   @Override
override fun onDrag(v: View?, event: DragEvent?): Boolean {
    if (event != null) {
        when (event.action) {
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
                if (event.clipDescription.hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                    if (v != null) {
                        if (v.isHovered) {
                            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN)
                            v.invalidate()
                        }
                    }

                }
                val o1: Any = gv?.adapter?.getItem(position) as Any
                if (o1 is Int) dImage1 = o1
            }

            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> {
                val o1: Any = gv?.adapter?.getItem(position) as Any
                if (o1 is Int) dImage1 = o1
            }

            DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                // Depending of the three ImageViews hovered over by shadow, that 
                 ImageView
                // shall obtain the drawable.
                dImage1?.let { category1?.setImageResource(it) }
                category1?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                t1 =
                    category1?.let {
                        shoppingVM.getClipData(dImage1.toString(), it).toString()
                    }
                return true
            }

            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED -> if (v != null) {
                v.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION -> {}
        }
    }
    return true
    }
```

Then in another activity I would do this in Kotlin:

```
val dragDrop: DragDrop

val parcel: Parcel = Parcel.obtain()                                                    
parcel.writeInt(mEvent.action);                                                         
parcel.writeFloat(xPos);                                                                
parcel.writeFloat(yPos);                                                                
parcel.writeInt(0); // Result when (mEvent.action) {                                    
parcel.writeInt(0); // No Clipdata    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {                      
parcel.writeInt(0); // No Clip Description        if (dragDrop.onDrag(view, dragEvent) )
parcel.setDataPosition(0);                                                              
val dragEvent: DragEvent = DragEvent.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel)                   
var categoryTag: String = merchImageAdapter.merchImages[clickPos]                       
                                                                                    
if (dragDrop.onDrag(view, dragEvent)) {                                                 
when (dragEvent.action){                                                            
    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ->{                                                     
         dragDrop.updateDragData(categoryTag, view)                                 
    }                                                                               
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ->{                                                       
          categoryTag =  merchImageAdapter.merchImages[0]                           
    }                                                                               
    MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ->{                                                     
                                                                                    
    }                                                                               
                                                                                    
  }
```

The reason for the Parcel is to initialize the dragEvent parameter to pass into the onDrag override method.  In my actual code, I wanted to add everything that is related to drag and drop functionality so I've also included RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener and it's methods in the same DragDrop class.  The ultimate reason for this confusion is that in one activity I'm dragging and dropping from a gridview and in another I'm dragging and dropping from a RecyclerView.  I've read in the documentation somewhere that RecyclerView handles all the views like gridview, listview, etc..